# i don't know how to do an embedded relation between users and permission in sfguard

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I have my `sf_guard_user` with its fields and i want to create an embedded relation between the permission and users in order to have a form, in `sf_guard_user`, able to add or modify permission for a users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a form with this class `sfGuardUserForm`. And inside this class, you have a widget called `sf_guard_user_permission_list` that handle permissions relation.